# Dlib,python,face_detection with neural network

Tags: python, face-detection, dlib

### When ever i tried to load the trained model of 
[cnn based face_detector](http://dlib.net/files/mmod_human_face_detector.dat.bz2)in dlib.i got this error.

```
detector = dlib.simple_object_detector('mmod_human_face_detector.dat')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/hasans/Desktop/1/face_recognition1/face_detector.py", line 51, in <module>

detector = dlib.simple_object_detector('mmod_human_face_detector.dat')
RuntimeError: Unsupported version found when deserializing a scan_fhog_pyramid object</br>
```

### how to get rid of this error?

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNN based face detector is now officially available  for using in python in its latest release 19.6.Everyone can  download it from

https://dlib.net

cheers !!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you got your code from, but the cnn-based face-detector is used differently, as given in [this official demo](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/python_examples/cnn_face_detector.py).

Init looks like:

```
cnn_face_detection_model = dlib.cnn_face_detection_model_v1('mmod_human_face_detector.dat')
```

(I used it successfully)

**Warning:** the python-wrapper needed for this was only recently added (18.8.17) and as of now (3 days later) is only available within git, not any official release!